# My function won't work if I add a priority…

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I am having trouble with a plugin on wordpress.  Basically I want to run some code for an ad at the bottom of the post content, and I found this code that does it.  the problem is there are other plugins that are appending stuff at the bottom of the post content as well, and they are above my ad code.  So I tried putting priority of "1" on the "add_filter" statement and that made this function stop working.  But when I remove the priority of 1 then the function works fine.  So can anyone shed any light on this?  I am trying to make it so wordpress appends mine onto content first or second before stuff from other plugins...

```
function pippin_filter_content_sample6($content) {
if( is_single() && is_main_query() ) {
    $new_content = '<br/><div align="center">
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- New Below Content Ad -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:250px"
data-ad-client="ca-pub-6714748819685572"
data-ad-slot="5357269200"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script></div>';
    $content .= $new_content;   
}   
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'pippin_filter_content_sample6', 1);
```

Comment: You can play with priority and try values between 2 and 11...

Comment: Hello Lumiere:  thanks for your input - it actually does not work on any priority number, i have tried several...